# How to recover from COM error gracefully?

Tags: c++, com, mfc

I have a third party COM component with its c++ interface in VC++. I am getting a crash in the call below which is crashing my application. How can I recover gracefully from this function which is not really part of my application?

```
inline _RecordsetPtr IGLibMgr::GetLibInfo ( _bstr_t LibPath ) {
    struct _Recordset * _result = 0;
    HRESULT _hr = raw_GetLibInfo(LibPath, &_result);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _RecordsetPtr(_result, false);
}
```

It crashes in the last line. I don't think I can modify this code since it's third party COM stuff. What options do I really have? I just want to bring up message box to user and return gracefully.

Comment: Are you *sure* it isn't "crashing" because you're not catching a `_com_error&` that is being thrown due to a `FAILED(_hr)` status? If you debugged this I would *almost* guarantee the hresult being generated has the SEVERITY bit lit (the thing that causes `FAILED()` to eval to non-zero)

Comment: I am just not familiar with COM, do I need to catch it with catch() block?

Comment: Yes. The general rule is, if an exception can be thrown, either you need to catch and handle it, or ***know*** that your caller will do so. It sounds like neither is being done. The `comutil` support layer from MSVC is pretty strong; almost a methodology in its own. I've include a sample of how you can handle this below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not already doing this in your code, you need to be from the caller-side:

```
try
{   // setup your invoke for your object...
    IGLibMgrPtr spMgr = ....
    bstr_t bstrPath = ....

    // invoke your call.
    _RecordsetPtr spRS = spMgr->GetLibInfo(bstrPath);

    ... continue normal processing ...
}
catch(const _com_error& ce)
{
    // handle your error here.
}
```

This is important on multiple levels. The most obvious being that not only can your `IGLibMgr` member throw an exception, so can the `bstr_t` allocation, etc. When using `#import` code from a COM DLL, get used to this format if using generated smart-pointers from the comutil library of MSVC.

Note: The `_com_error` class provides several members for obtaining why the error happened, including the HRESULT, error description string, etc. It even provides access to the `IErrorInfo` created by the error-returning object if it is so-nice as to provide that level of detail.

Comment: Better catch with const: 'catch (const _com_error & ex) {...}'